# How to extract values from top level, by checking nested value?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I need to extract all `organizer_inn` and `organizer_name` if `suppliers` `winner` is `"True"`.

For example I need extract all `organizer_inn` where `0278197430`.

My code is next:

```
var data = [{
        "registration_number": "0301300020720000004",
        "organizer_name": "Foo",
        "organizer_inn": "026814121",
        "fas_complaints": "False",
        "lots": {
                "suppliers": [{
                        "winner": "True",
                        "inn": "0278209090"
                }]
        }
}, 
{
        "registration_number": "0301300020720000004",
        "organizer_name": "Bar",
        "organizer_inn": "0268019693",
        "fas_complaints": "False",
        "lots": {
                "suppliers": [{
                        "winner": "True",
                        "inn": "0278209090"
                }]
        }
},


{
        "registration_number": "0301300020720000002",
        "organizer_name": "Bar2",
        "organizer_inn": "7243435493",
        "fas_complaints": "False",
        "lots": {
                "suppliers": [{
                        "winner": "False",
                        "inn": "0278197430"

                }, {
                        "winner": "False",
                        "inn": "0278216877"
                }, {
                        "winner": "True",
                        "inn": "0268021212"
                }]
        }
}, {
        "registration_number": "0301300020720000003",
        "organizer_name": "some",
        "organizer_inn": "0234534533",
        "fas_complaints": "False",
        "lots": {
                "suppliers": [{
                        "winner": "True",
                        "inn": "0278197430"
                }]
        }
} ]

// I tried to start with ... 
data.forEach(el => el.lots.suppliers.forEach( s => {
        if(s.inn == "0278197430") 
        {
          if(s.winner == "True") {

          }
        }
}
) )
```

Could anybody help?

Comment: there is no `organizer_inn` where value is  `0278197430`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var data = [{
    "registration_number": "0301300020720000004",
    "organizer_name": "Foo",
    "organizer_inn": "026814121",
    "fas_complaints": "False",
    "lots": {
      "suppliers": [{
        "winner": "True",
        "inn": "0278209090"
      }]
    }
  },
  {
    "registration_number": "0301300020720000004",
    "organizer_name": "Bar",
    "organizer_inn": "0268019693",
    "fas_complaints": "False",
    "lots": {
      "suppliers": [{
        "winner": "True",
        "inn": "0278209090"
      }]
    }
  },


  {
    "registration_number": "0301300020720000002",
    "organizer_name": "Bar2",
    "organizer_inn": "7243435493",
    "fas_complaints": "False",
    "lots": {
      "suppliers": [{
        "winner": "False",
        "inn": "0278197430"

      }, {
        "winner": "False",
        "inn": "0278216877"
      }, {
        "winner": "True",
        "inn": "0268021212"
      }]
    }
  }, {
    "registration_number": "0301300020720000003",
    "organizer_name": "some",
    "organizer_inn": "0234534533",
    "fas_complaints": "False",
    "lots": {
      "suppliers": [{
        "winner": "True",
        "inn": "0278197430"
      }]
    }
  }
]

const output = [];
data.forEach(item => {
  if (item.lots.suppliers.findIndex(s => s.winner === "True" && s.inn === '0278197430' ) !== -1)
    output.push({
      organizer_inn: item.organizer_inn,
      organizer_name: item.organizer_name,
    });
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks! What `!== -1` is do?

Comment: that means there is an item that matches the search criteria.
if nothing found, findIndex returns -1

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for this.

```js
const winners = data.filter(org => {
  return org.lots.suppliers.find(supplier => {
    return supplier.inn === '0278197430' && supplier.winner === 'True';
  });
});
```

```js
const data = [{
        "registration_number": "0301300020720000004",
        "organizer_name": "Foo",
        "organizer_inn": "026814121",
        "fas_complaints": "False",
        "lots": {
                "suppliers": [{
                        "winner": "True",
                        "inn": "0278209090"
                }]
        }
}, 
{
        "registration_number": "0301300020720000004",
        "organizer_name": "Bar",
        "organizer_inn": "0268019693",
        "fas_complaints": "False",
        "lots": {
                "suppliers": [{
                        "winner": "True",
                        "inn": "0278209090"
                }]
        }
},


{
        "registration_number": "0301300020720000002",
        "organizer_name": "Bar2",
        "organizer_inn": "7243435493",
        "fas_complaints": "False",
        "lots": {
                "suppliers": [{
                        "winner": "False",
                        "inn": "0278197430"

                }, {
                        "winner": "False",
                        "inn": "0278216877"
                }, {
                        "winner": "True",
                        "inn": "0268021212"
                }]
        }
}, {
        "registration_number": "0301300020720000003",
        "organizer_name": "some",
        "organizer_inn": "0234534533",
        "fas_complaints": "False",
        "lots": {
                "suppliers": [{
                        "winner": "True",
                        "inn": "0278197430"
                }]
        }
} ];

const winners = data.filter(org => org.lots.suppliers.find(supplier => supplier.inn === '0278197430' && supplier.winner === 'True'));
console.log(winners);
```

Answer (score 0):

here it is : use array.filter(), arra.some() and array.map()  methods

```js
const data = 
    [ { registration_number: '0301300020720000004'
      , organizer_name     : 'Foo'
      , organizer_inn      : '026814121'
      , fas_complaints     : 'False'
      , lots: 
        { suppliers: 
          [ { winner: 'True', inn: '0278209090' } ] 
      } } 
    , { registration_number: '0301300020720000004'
      , organizer_name     : 'Bar'
      , organizer_inn      : '0268019693'
      , fas_complaints     : 'False'
      , lots: 
        { suppliers: 
          [ { winner: 'True', inn: '0278209090' } ] 
      } } 
    , { registration_number: '0301300020720000002'
      , organizer_name     : 'Bar2'
      , organizer_inn      : '7243435493'
      , fas_complaints     : 'False'
      , lots: 
        { suppliers: 
          [ { winner: 'False', inn: '0278197430' } 
          , { winner: 'False', inn: '0278216877' } 
          , { winner: 'True',  inn: '0268021212' } 
          ] 
      } } 
    , { registration_number: '0301300020720000003'
      , organizer_name     : 'some'
      , organizer_inn      : '0234534533'
      , fas_complaints     : 'False'
      , lots: 
        { suppliers: 
          [ { winner: 'True', inn: '0278197430' } ] 
      } } 
    ] 


const output = data
              .filter(el=>el.lots.suppliers.some(s=>
                                s.winner==='True'  && s.inn==='0278197430'))
              .map(({organizer_inn,organizer_name})=>({organizer_inn,organizer_name}))

console.log( output )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100% !important;top: 0;}
```